# Trouble toggling between login/signup forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having trouble toggling between my signup and login forms on a page. I'm not too familiar with JavaScript and jQuery but that is what I am using. BTW, is there another way to do this with PHP?

Here's what I've got. My login form is shown when the page is loaded, and the signup form is hidden. When I click the toggle button to show the signup form, nothing happens.

```js
$("#toggle-login").click(function() {
  $("#signup").hide().attr("formnovalidate");
  $("#login").show();
});

$("#toggle-signup").click(function() {
  $("#login").hide().attr("formnovalidate");
  $("#signup").show();
});

$("document").ready(function() {
  $("#signup").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-data text-center">
  <h1 class="form-header">Header</h1>
  <div id="login" class="main-login">
    <form class="login-form" action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
      <input name="mailuid" type="text" placeholder="Page Name"></input>
      <br>
      <input name="pwd" type="password" placeholder="Password"></input>
      <br>
      <button name="login-submit" type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
    <p>Need to Create an account?</p>
    <span class="btn btn-default" href="#" id="toggle-signup">Sign Up/span>
        </div>
    
        <div id="signup" class="main-signup text-center">
            <form class="signup-form" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
              <input name="pagename" type="text" placeholder="Page Name"></input>
              <br>
              <input name="pwd" type="password" placeholder="Password"></input>
              <br>
              <input name="pwd-repeat" type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password"></input>
              <br>
              <button name="login-submit" type="submit">Login</button>
            </form>
            <p>Already have an account?</p>
            <span class="btn btn-default" href="#" id="toggle-login">Log In</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery? Check your console for errors? I pasted your code into a snippet and it appears to work fine. Side note, there's a small typo in `Sign Up/span>` (but that wouldn't cause your issue)

Comment: it works in the "run snippet"

Comment: your code snippet is working fine for me, you just missed to close the span after sign up 'Sign Up/span>' but that shooldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the `<script>` block to the bottom of your page. Currently you are trying to attach event click handlers for DOM-Elements that are not present at the moment when the script block is executed.

Alternatively you can move the jQuery click handlers into the `jQuery('document').ready()` function to make sure the DOM is ready when attaching the click handlers.

Answer (score -1):

Have your script defer so that it loads after the html has loaded

```
<script src="name_of_your_js_file" defer>
```

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) re: `defer`: _"This attribute must not be used if the src attribute is absent (i.e. for inline scripts), in this case it would have no effect."_

Comment: Yes, I just assumed that their JavaScript would be in an external file.